# How many times a word appears in a TXT file

Tags: java, string

I have a problem when I try to count how many times a word appears in a TXT file.

1. I create a textfield ( **txta** )
2. I create a button to apply the action ( **btn** )
3. I create a textarea ( **area** ) where the content of the file is displayed

When I select the file, the content of the file is displayed in **area**. Then I enter the word in **txta** to search. I then click the **btn**, but the code does not work.

```
public int contarPalabras(String chain, String word) {
    // English translation: 
    // Receive a string and a word and return the amount of times 
    // that the word was found in the string.
    // If the letter is not found, return (-1).

    int cant = 0; 

    int intIndex = chain.indexOf(word);

    if (intIndex == -1) {
        cant = -1;
    } else {
        cant = intIndex;
    }

    return cant;
}
```

Comment: How does that method differ from `return chain.indexOf(word);`?

Comment: because if the file retrieve: "Esta es una prueba de donde se abre el archivo" and the word to find is: una.. the result is: 8

Comment: Let me rephrase my original comment, because you didn't seem to understand it: **The code you posted is identical to `public int contarPalabras(String chain, String word) { return chain.indexOf(word); }`.** Do you understand my point now?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by word? Is `jhhldasf` a word? Is `:-)` a word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`String.indexOf(string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29). It does not do what you think it does. It returns **only the index of first occurrence** of the parameter.

In order to get it work you can do something like this:

```
public int countWord(String chain, String word){
    if("".equal(word)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("word is empty string"); // error when word is empty string
    }
    index = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (index != -1){
        int found = chain.indexOf(word, index);
        if(found != -1){
            count++;
            index = found + word.length();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really just want to count complete words (that is substrings separated by spaces from both sides) this version will be more useful:

```
public int countWord(String chain, String word){
    if("".equal(word)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("word is empty string"); // error when word is empty string
    }
    index = 0;
    count = 0;
    word = " " + word + " ";
    while (index != -1){
        int found = chain.indexOf(word, index);
        if(found != -1){
            count++;
            index = found + word.length() - 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: In case you want to find also overlaping words for example you want that for text `aaa` and word `aa` you get answer `2` not `1` you can just replace `index = found + word.length();` by `index = found + 1;`

Answer (score 4):

commons-lang has [`StringUtils.countMatches(str, sub)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: But I've to download the package because it doesn't retrieved by Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2 answers given will have the following problem:
in the text: "Saturdays and Sundays are my favourite days" if you seach for "days", it will return: 3 because it will match Satur **days**, Sun **days** and **days**.
I assume you want to match only **days**

In that case you have to use regex, here is the answer:

```
public int countWord(String chain, String word){
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(chain);

  int count = 0;
  while(m.find()) {
    count++;             
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: You are right... I considered "word" to be just some substring not really a word. I'll edit my answer.